# How to set custom intervals in the horizontal axis in Google Charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I'm using Google Charts. I gave it this data:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
   {
     cols: [{id: 'date', label: 'Date of like', type: 'date'},
            {id: 'likes', label: 'Number of likes', type: 'number'}],
     rows: [{c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 00, 00)}, {v: 2}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 11, 20)}, {v: 2}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 11, 25)}, {v: 4}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 11, 30)}, {v: 15}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 12, 45)}, {v: 30}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 13, 15)}, {v: 45}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 14, 05)}, {v: 63}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 16, 20)}, {v: 69}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 18, 45)}, {v: 74}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 20, 05)}, {v: 76}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 23, 45)}, {v: 77}]},
            {c:[{v: new Date(2012, 7, 10, 24, 00)}, {v: 77}]}
           ]
   }
```

In the Date function, the last 2 numbers are the hour and the number of minutes. The problem is Google Charts seems to only allow me to display the day of the dates as values (gridlines) in the horizontal axis, but I'd like to display the hours within a day. Google Charts doesn't seem to scale lower than the unit of 'one day'.

Is there a way I could display hours in the horizontal axis? Thanks in advance.